# Сеть из 3 компьютеров (200 метров)

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Мне нужна сеть(локалка, без интернета) из 3 компьютеров. 2 компьютера рядом, а третий унесен на 200 метров.Вопрос в том, как организовать эту сеть.Я думаю поставить маршрутизатор около 2 компов. Мне кажется пойдет любой маршрутизатор.А до третьего, удаленного компа как тянуть я не представляю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошую (с маленькой потерей) витую пару, и устройства, которые поставить на данном маршруте и на каких расстояниях.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вариант который был успешно опробован - vdsl модем.Варианты: http://zyxel.ru/catalog/classifier/1/11/34http://market.yandex.ru/guru.xml?CMD=-RR=0,0,0,0-PF=2142560255~EQ~sel~x86454155-VIS=8070-CAT_ID=106824-EXC=1-PG=10&hid=91029Единственное, желательное условие: выделенный телефонный кабель.

Comment: На настоящий момент использую такой вариант (по vdsl).Из проблем: таки да, необходимо обеспечивать линию, скорее всего через городскую АТС; периодически (когда два раза в день, а когда и раз в два месяца) пропадает линк между модемами. Предположительно, что-то глючит на АТС (_предположительно!_), но возможно и модемы... Лечится прозвонкой линии и/или ребутом (есть не мое мнение, что необходима синхронность) модемов.

Comment: в моем случае выделенный кабель обеспечили наши связисты. это я к тому что можно и напрямую пробросить кабель телефонный и соединить ими модемы.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не маршрутизатор, а коммутатор.
2. Любая пара 5(5e)UTP категории.
3. На расстоянии 100м ставьте повторитель или самый простой коммутатор.

Comment: если п. 3 невыполним, поможет опта либо направленная антенна wifi

Comment: Да зачем же напраленная-то? Ещё и угол ловить??? Проще репитер (повторитель) поставить!

Comment: а если "если п. 3 невыполним"? т.е. это чужая территория, на которой не разместишь оборудование или нет 220В.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее, на мой взгляд, решение (если гигабитной скорости в локалке не надо) - третий, дальний комп, подключить по WiFi! Адаптер WiFi стоит рублей 600, что по цене дешевле 200 метров UTP. Кроме того, стенки долбить не надо! Если проходимость сигнала совсем плоха (к примеру, четыре железобетонные стены), то можно купить какой-нибудь дешёвый TP-Link (680 рублей, недавно покупал), и воткнуть его повторителем. Всё равно, обойдётся дешевле, чем протягивание UTP!

Comment: Пятак, кстати, тут мудро заметил, что в локалке без выхода наружу - это коммутатор, а не маршрутизатор. Но одно другому не мешает! Чем удобней WiFi - не надо пробивать и штробить стены, и тянуть кабель! Кроме того, давно уже существуют сетевые принтеры с подключением по WiFi. Ну, это я так, до кучи...

Comment: ТС явно дал понять "Подскажите пожалуйста хорошую(***с маленькой потерей***)".

Comment: С "маленькой потерей" - это токовая петля 60 миллиампер! Её хоть по земле голыми проводами клади - работать будет!Скорость, правда, низкая...

Comment: Я в контексте вариантов приближенных к задаче ТС.

Comment: А ему шашечки или ехать? Я же предложил вариант, нас собственной шкуре проверенный! У меня там хоть и дистанция поменьше была, но через лестничную площадку, и вполэтажа по высоте. Подвесные потолки были только внутренние, а так как помещение арендовано, а не в собственности, дырки через лестницу бурить запретили. Пришлось делать Вай-Фай с Вай-Файным же репитером. Я же знаю, о чём пишу.

Comment: на 200 метров никакая самая лучшая из лучших витых пар в протоколе ethernet 100Mbps работать не будет :) без свитча

Comment: Есть такая глупая практика - включать две из четырёх, а по остатним телефон разводить. Вот так - точно не будет! А если правильно сделать - работает, при стандарте 100 метров. А у меня и на 300 долбило!!! Практика, уважаемый, иногда очень сильно опровергает теорию, только не надо делать глупостей!

Answer (score 0):

Вставлю свои 5 коп.))

Я бы рекомендовал WiFi не точка+свисток, а пара точек в режиме бриджа. Расстояние все-таки, да и не известно, что там между... Не будет добивать - можно ткнуть еще одну в режиме репитера.

Если кого смутит стоимость - попробуйте подсчитать стоимость кабельный работ, добавьте согласование дырок в стенах/полах и п̶р̶о̶ч̶и̶й̶ ̶г̶е̶м̶о̶р̶р̶о̶й̶ другие возможные осложнения.

Comment: Спасибо! Ещё один чел независимо додумался до того, что я уже сделал, и прочим посоветовал.

Comment: Сарказм?;-)К сожалению, предпочитаю учиться на собственном опыте...

Answer (score 0):

Вот точка доступа от [trendnet](http://trendnet.ru/products/catalog/detail/TEW-676APBO), вроде бы по тестам в вашей ситуации заработает